# Why is my SD shield making my Arduino not power on?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, sd-card

I wanted to use an SD shield on an Arduino Elegoo to make a typewriter (for saving files).

I put the shield on the Arduino Elegoo, then connected an LCD screen, then tried to power on using USB to computer, but my Arduino Elegoo wouldn't power on.

I tried to power it on with the external power supply, but it still wouldn't power on.

If I power it on without the shield it works perfectly fine, so why is my Arduino Elegoo not powering on?

[image: the arduino elegoo with the sheild connected to the lcd screen]

Comment: When you say you "remove the shield" I assume that also implies removing that tangle of wires too? What about leaving the shield on but disconnecting the wires? I'll bet it works then. The problem won't be with the shield, it'll be a mistake in your own wiring.

Comment: Majenko  Yes you are correct it powers on without the wires but the lcd screen powers on without the sheild plus the elegoo powers on too whereas if i have the sheild and elegoo connected to the lcd screen then it does not work so how do i fix this since the lcd screen is important in the project

Comment: pins 10 to 13 are SPI pins used by the SD shield. it looks like you use the same pins for the LCD and I doubt the LCD works on SPI bus.

Comment: If you want to make your question answerable to the point of receiving specific instructions you'd need to include images of the sort of quality that would allow readers to trace each connection unambiguously. There are common SD card shield designs, but someone answering this would likely want to know exactly which design your shield follows. To get the sort of answer that would lead you to a successful outcome as a whole project you'd also want to include your code as well.

Comment: juraj yep you're right it worked